# Using preg_match to find all text between brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to search a document for tags, to later replace them.

I am using preg_match, but am having some difficulty.

```
preg_match('/\[.*\]/', $haystack, $matches);
```

Searching through the following text

[TODAY_DATE]

Re: Demand for Payment

[ADDRESS]
[ADDRESS_LINE_2]
...etc

```
print_r($matches);
```

returns

```
Array ( [0] => [TODAY_DATE] )
```

How should I adjust my regex to return all matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all`. As the name suggests, it matches more than once.

```
preg_match_all('/\[.*?\]/', $haystack, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Also use reluctant quantifier `.*?` instead of greedy one.